# More efficient way of running find on a Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes similar to this:

```rb
rules = [{
  "id" => "artist_name",
  "type" => "string",
  "field" => "artist_name",
  "input" => "text",
  "value" => "Underoath",
  "operator" => "contains"
},
{
  "id" => "bpm",
  "type" => "integer",
  "field" => "bpm",
  "input" => "number",
  "value" => 100,
  "operator" => "greater"
}]
```

I'm running a `find` on that to select the hash I want:

`rules.find {|h| h['id'] == 'artist_name'}`

But I'm needing to do this for dozens of different "rules" and this feels a bit verbose.

Maybe it is in fact the most efficient way to grab a specific "rule", but my hunch is there's a Ruby method that can potentially do this better.

If I just need to write my own method, that's fine, but wanted to see if there's a way to do this I'm not familiar with.

So, is there a way to write `rules.find {|h| h['id'] == 'artist_name'}` in a more compact/efficient manner?

Comment: Are you asking for a faster algorithm to find elements? If you're calling this many-many times, it can be advantageous to make a new data structure to speed up searches

Comment: You can use `index_by` but it will only improve performance if you are looking up multiple values for the same key, e.g. `rules.index_by { |x| x["id"] }.values_at "bpm", "artist_name"` is better performance than `["bpm", "artist_name"].map { |id| rules.find { |x| x["id"] == id } }`

Comment: If you are going to search for records regularly you should consider using a database.

Comment: @max, my people tell me that `index_by` is a Rails method. (No Rails tag.)

Comment: I always forget about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find a hash for a single value of `"id"`, then you obviously you must perform a linear search. On the other hand, if you wish to do multiple look-ups for different values of `"id"`, then you'd be wise to create a hash with the appropriate keys.

```
rules = [{
  "id"       => "artist_name",
  "type"     => "string",
  "field"    => "artist_name",
  "input"    => "text",
  "value"    => "Underoath",
  "operator" => "contains"
},
{
  "id"       => "bpm",
  "type"     => "integer",
  "field"    => "bpm",
  "input"    => "number",
  "value"    => 100,
  "operator" => "greater"
}]
```

```
h = rules.each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(g,i),h| h[g["id"]] = i }
  #=> {"artist_name"=>0, "bpm"=>1}
```

The values of `h` are indices of elements (hashes) of `rules`. The hash for `"id"=>"bpm"` is therefore

```
rules[h["bpm"]
  #=> {"id"=>"bpm", "type"=>"integer", "field"=>"bpm", "input"=>"number",
  #    "value"=>100, "operator"=>"greater"}
```

I could have made the values of `h` the elements of `rules` themselves, but that would require more storage without providing a significant improvement in lookup times.

It's not clear from the question if the value of `"id"` could be the same for two or more elements of `rules`. If that is the case `h` will have fewer keys than `rules` has elements, but the wording of the question suggests that any hash among those with the same value of `"id"` could be selected.

Answer (score 2):

You could try grouping by `id`, and make that the hash key to lookup against. E.g.

```
grouped_rules = rules.group_by { |r| r["id"] }
# => {"artist_name"=>[{"id"=>"artist_name", "type"=>"string", "field"=>"artist_name", "input"=>"text", "value"=>"Underoath", "operator"=>"contains"}], "bpm"=>[{"id"=>"bpm", "type"=>"integer", "field"=>"bpm", "input"=>"number", "value"=>100, "operator"=>"greater"}]}

grouped_rules["artist_name"]
# => [{"id"=>"artist_name", "type"=>"string", "field"=>"artist_name", "input"=>"text", "value"=>"Underoath", "operator"=>"contains"}]
```

This is definitely more compact and readable, but whether it's "efficient" depends on how you intend to measure/evaluate that. This isn't more memory efficient, but should be faster if you previously used `find` a lot.